# DjangoRestFramework - How to update fields in model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using Django user model and also extended with my own profile model for some other data.When i want to update user data which is in Profile Model It doesn't get updated because all the user id,username,email,password reside in user model while the fields which are needed to get updated are in profile model.I have used this approach, all it does is takes inputs and displays the response but does not show any change in User Data when viewing it as a whole.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    friends_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    profile_pic = models.FileField(upload_to='profile_pics/',blank=True,null=True)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.user.username,)
```

**views.py**

```
class UserCreateAPIViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet,mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    """"A View which handles  Creating  and Updating User Profile"""
    serializer_class = UserProfileCreateSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateOwnProfile,)

    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('username','email',)

class UserUpdateAPI(generics.GenericAPIView,mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    """Update User Profile Data"""
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateOwnProfile,)
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileUpdateSerializer

    def put(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^user-update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.UserUpdateAPI.as_view(),name="user-update"),
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'profile',views.UserCreateAPIViewSet)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """"A serializer for user data request"""
    location = serializers.CharField(source='profile.location')
    friends_count = serializers.IntegerField(source='profile.friends_count',read_only=True)
    profile_pic = serializers.FileField(source='profile.profile_pic',allow_empty_file=True,allow_null=True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'location',
            'friends_count',
            'profile_pic',
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password':{'write_only':True},
            'friends_count':{'read_only':True},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """"Create and return a new User"""


        user = User(
            email = validated_data['email'],
            username = validated_data['username']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])

        user.save()

        return user

class ProfileUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for updating user data"""
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('location','profile_pic')
```

Comment: You are updating `Profile` model data. not **`User`** model data

Comment: If you want to update both of them search for inline formsets

Comment: Yeah!!! It depends on what the user requests,If he wants to update password it must be done,If he wants to edit his profile_pic it must be updated.....I will update the question with views for user model.

Comment: I am using rest apis for android app how Inline Formsets would be helpful for that? @alex

Comment: In `UserProfileCreateSerializer`, you are saving the `User` object, but not saving the `Profile` object.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to extend from the AbstractBaseUser (see code below), using this as your `UserProfileCreateSerializer`:

```
class UserProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """"A serializer for user data request"""
    location = serializers.CharField(source='profile.location')
    friends_count = serializers.IntegerField(source='profile.friends_count',read_only=True)
    profile_pic = serializers.FileField(source='profile.profile_pic',allow_empty_file=True,allow_null=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'location',
            'friends_count',
            'profile_pic',
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password':{'write_only':True},
            'friends_count':{'read_only':True},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
         """"Create and return a new User"""


        user = Profile(
             email = validated_data['email'],
             username = validated_data['username']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])

        user.save()

        return user

class ProfileUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for updating user data"""
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('location','profile_pic')
```

Then extend from the `AbstractBaseUser` in `models.py`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .managers import ProfileManager

class Profile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    friends_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    profile_pic =  models.FileField(upload_to='profile_pics/',blank=True,null=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        '''
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the short name for the user.
        '''
        return self.first_name

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.username,)

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        '''
        Sends an email to this User.
        '''
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

And then create a file called `managers.py` in the same directory as `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

To wrap all this up you need to add this to your `settings.py` file:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.Profile'
```

And also don't forget to re-run all database migrations before using `$ python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: You cant call `set_password` method on a `Profile` instance.

Comment: Please check the `Profile` model. This doesnt solve any problems, but will raise more errors.

Comment: @SachinKukreja Yes - you're quite right - I'm going to modify this for a custom user `Model`.

Comment: That just work's fine for me!!! What do i need to change and why? Can anyone of you explain me clearly.

Comment: @DilipKrishna Hi Dilip - it allows you to extend from all of the `AbstractBase` user fields, giving you access to `Profile.username` and `Profile.password`.

Comment: I am already using user model as one to one field.Are AbstractUser and User different or else all i just need to do is update my code as you said?

Comment: Hi Dilip - I know, but for what you want you want to extend everything from your the default Django `User`, it makes linking everything a whole lot easier and focuses you on one combined `User`/`Profile` model. Otherwise, to do this you'd need to create them as a `User` first then allow then to edit/update their Profile related details from there...a little trickier to handle. Have a look through at all of the User extend methods or ways of linking what you need here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: @DilipKrishna I've updated my question to hopefully give you a full idea of how to extend from the `AbstractBaseUser` Django ships with. Using the `UserProfileCreateSerializer()` I outlined above with the extended `Profile` model should now work. Let me know if you run into errors etc.

Comment: OH!!! Do I have to change my entire user model......Will that effect my DB ?Thank you so much....I will try it and let you know in the comments about it.

Comment: @DilipKrishna This method will need a clear out of all `User` related migrations, deletion of `User` related tables in your DB and then a re-run of migrations...I assume you're still in testing/development?

Comment: @DilipKrishna Ideal, yes, definitely use this extending method then - this gives much more flexibility further down the line if you want to add tokens and other custom API related stuffs. :) Once your `User` model is defined, it's extremely tricky to change this (and requires some advanced Django knowledge and good knowledge of the migration process, and Django DB schemas etc).